# SharePoint PWA 2013 - Visitor Access Issue

Tags: 2013, security, access, project-server, pwa

so I am working with SharePoint 2013 Project Web App security and it's giving unexpected access issues.

1. So in PWA security Manage Group settings, I added a new user to the Portfolio Viewers group, after saving, I checked the project site permission, I see that the user has been added successfully to the "Visitor" group. I made sure the user is not in any other group, only in the Visitor group. The user was able to logon and view the project home page, however, unable to view any lists (risks, issues, tasks lists), or library (document library). Only the home page.
2. Removing the user from the PWA Manage Group setting does not remove the user from the Visitor group, even tho it's said "PWA Sync", is this by design?

Please let me know if anyone has any idea how to resolve either issue.

Comment: what's the permission mode that you have used in PWA? is it a project permission mode, please confirm